# EMMS read .ogg tags?

Tags: emms

**Q:** how can I get EMMS to read .ogg file tags?

After a fresh system install, EMMS does not read .ogg tags.  I've
looked at the source code for `emms-info-ogginfo`, and it uses the
variable `emms-info-ogginfo-program-name`, which is set to
`ogginfo`, which I have on my system.  When I run `ogginfo` from
the command line, it correctly returns the tags.

Interestingly, it looks like EMMS finds/uses *some* but not all of the tags.  It appears to get the date and genre correct, but does not populate the track number, artist, or track title.

What gives, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I recommend asking the developers at emms-help@gnu.org: they are responsive and helpful.